# Camera Roll asset images not available after saving an image to Saved Photos

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, alassetslibrary

I am using `ALAssetsLibrary` to make an array of all images in the camera roll when my iPhone app starts. I store every image as a `ALAsset *` in an array. 
Later in the app, I am saving an image to the gallery using this:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

The image is saved successfully to the saved photos album. But, now my problem is that when I try to retrieve images using the existing array of all images, I don't get anything. Do I need to build the array of all images again or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving an image changes the library and invalidates objects like assets from the library. You need to reload assets from the library whenever the library changes - do that when you receive an `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification`.